# Problems with gif files in apache web server

Tags: apache, web, http-status-code-404

We have an Apache Webserver, Version 2.4.12 on a Windows 2008 machine.
We have gif images in different sub folders of htdocs, some in "icons" and some other in "ni5/customer/images".
When I start our web application, the Google Chrome developer tools show something strange:

[image]

The one gif image from "ni5/customer/images" is loaded and the type is "gif", the other gif image from "icons" is NOT loaded and the type is "text/html".

When I open the second one with a image viewer, it is recognized as "gif".

Answer (score 1):

The second image is not found on the server on that location or under that name.
It results in a 404 not found error(that's why the 404 response code is there).

The 404 not found response is usually always a text based response served from the defined error pages.

Just make sure you have the path and filename correct. Might be the result of a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

It was a name conflict!

I typed in the browser "http://localhost/icons/aktansicht3.gif" and found nothing.

Then I change "icons" into "icons2" and typed 
     "http://localhost/icons2/aktansicht3.gif" and it was found.

In Apache conf there was the entry:

Alias /icons/ "C:/xampp/apache/icons/"

So the "icons" directory was redirected to another location.

Now the alias is deleted from the conf and everything works.